# Hibernate - OneToMany annotation resulting in select query with mismatched left join

Tags: java, hibernate

I've three tables with one to many relationship between table 1 -- table 2 and between table2 -- and table3.

Table1 has composite primary key with two columns - Col_A & Col_B

> ### Table1
>
> Col_A
>   Col_B
>   ....other columns

Tabl2 has composite primary key with three columns Col_A, Col_B and Col_C. 
Col_A & Col_B values come from Table1 but there is no Foreign key relationship defined in the database schema (this is an old legacy database.. and I can't add constraints now because of the data issues)

> ### Table2
>
> Col_A
>   Col_B
>   Col_C
>   ---other columns

Table3 has composite primary key with four columns. Again, there is no foreign key relationship between table 2 and table3.

> ### Table3
>
> Col_A
>
> Col_B
>
> Col_C
>
> Col_D
>
> ---- other columns

And I've defined my domain object mapping in following way..

```
ClassOne{

    @Id
    @EmbeddedId
    private TableOneId id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "classOne")  
    private Set<ClassTwo> classTwoList = new HashSet<ClassTwo>(0); 

}

 TableOneId{
     //I've omitted the column name annotations for simplicity
      private String colA;
      private String colB;
}

ClassTwo{

    @Id
    @EmbeddedId
    private TableTwoId id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "classTwo")  
    private Set<ClassThree> classTwoList = new HashSet<ClassThree>(0); 

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
       @JoinColumn(name="COL_A",insertable=false, updatable=false),
       @JoinColumn(name="COL_B",insertable=false, updatable=false) 
    })
    private ClassOne classOne;
}

 TableTwoId{
      private String colA;
      private String colB;
      private String colC;
}


ClassThree{

    @Id
    @EmbeddedId
    private TableThreeId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
       @JoinColumn(name="COL_A",insertable=false, updatable=false),
       @JoinColumn(name="COL_B",insertable=false, updatable=false) ,
       @JoinColumn(name="COL_C",insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private ClassTwo classTwo;
}

 TableThreeId{
      private String colA;
      private String colB;
      private String colC;
      private String colD;
}
```

With the above mapping configuration, inserts into the three tables are working as expected. When I call session.save(classOne), I can see that the records are getting inserted into all three tables.

But when I retrieve ClassOne from DB, the resulting select SQL has left join with incorrect columns..

```
ClassOne classOne = (ClassOne )session.get(ClassOne .class, id);
```

> select **** from Table1 t1 left join Table2 t2 on t1.col_a = t2.col_a
>   and t1.col_b = t2.col_b left join Table3 t3 on t2.col_a = t3.col_a and
>   **t2.col_b = t3.col_c** and **t2.col_c = t3.col_b**

As you see above, left join between t2 and t3 has wrong column association.. how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show the annotations on `TableTwoId` and `TableThreeId`? By the way, good description of the problem.

Comment: @Rafa..thanks for the complement. I solved the issue by specifying `referencedColumnName` attribute in the `@JoinColumn` annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution..

I've added referenceColumn attribute in the JoinColumn and the issue has gone away. I can see that Hibernate SQL has correct association of left join.

```
ClassTwo{

    @Id
    @EmbeddedId
    private TableTwoId id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "classTwo")  
    private Set<ClassThree> classTwoList = new HashSet<ClassThree>(0); 

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
       @JoinColumn(name="COL_A",insertable=false, updatable=false, referencedColumnName="COL_A"),
       @JoinColumn(name="COL_B",insertable=false, updatable=false,referencedColumnName="COL_B") 
    })
    private ClassOne classOne;
}


ClassThree{

    @Id
    @EmbeddedId
    private TableThreeId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
       @JoinColumn(name="COL_A",insertable=false, updatable=false, referencedColumnName="COL_A"),
       @JoinColumn(name="COL_B",insertable=false, updatable=false, referencedColumnName="COL_B") ,
       @JoinColumn(name="COL_C",insertable=false, updatable=false, referencedColumnName="COL_C")
    })
    private ClassTwo classTwo;
}
```

now the generated SQL looks like

> select **** from Table1 t1 left join Table2 t2 on t1.col_a = t2.col_a
>   and t1.col_b = t2.col_b left join Table3 t3 on t2.col_a = t3.col_a and
>   t2.col_b = t3.col_b and t2.col_c = t3.col_c